# Transaction requires authority, but does not have signatures for it

Tags: eosjs, eosio.token

I am trying to send tokens from one account to another using eosjs & reactjs with the standard eosio.token contract but I have issues with the authority. Can someone please explain the meaning of the error message and share some resources on how authorities are used in EOS? I have tried reading the official documentation but I am still struggling to solve the issue.

Reacjs function:

```
static async tranfsferTokens (accountFrom, accountTo, quantity) {

try {
  (async () => { 
    console.log("Async func get_info");
    const resp = await api.transact({
    actions: [{
        account: 'eosio.token',
        name: 'transfer',
        authorization: [{
            actor: accountFrom,
            permission: 'active',
        }],
        data: {
            from: accountFrom,
            to: accountTo,
            quantity: quantity,
            memo: '',
        },
    }]
  }, {
    signatures: [signatureProvider],
    blocksBehind: 3,
    expireSeconds: 30,
  });
  pre.textContent += '\n\nTransaction pushed!\n\n' + JSON.stringify(resp, null, 2);
})();
} catch (e) {
  pre.textContent = '\nCaught exception: ' + e;
  if (e instanceof eosjs_jsonrpc.RpcError)
    pre.textContent += '\n\n' + JSON.stringify(e.json, null, 2);
}
```

}

Function call:

```
EosApiService.tranfsferTokens('alice', 'bob', '25 SYS');
```

Error message:

```
eosjs-rpcerror.js:26 Uncaught (in promise) Error: transaction declares authority '{"actor":"alice","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it.
at new RpcError (eosjs-rpcerror.js:26)
at JsonRpc.eval (eosjs-jsonrpc.js:118)
at step (eosjs-jsonrpc.js:36)
at Object.eval [as next] (eosjs-jsonrpc.js:17)
at fulfilled (eosjs-jsonrpc.js:8)
```

Comment: You probably don't provide the necessary keys for alice via the signatureprovider. Also you probably don't want to send SYS and instead EOS. In any case alice and bob need to be created on your local chain and you need the keys for alice account to sign the transaction.

Comment: Well actually I was doing everything of the above, but the problem was that I was providing only the owner key of alice. I added the active key also and it worked.

Comment: privateKeys:[defaultPrivateKey,bobPrivateKey,alicePrivateKey]

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error.

You need to set the keyProvider while initializing EOS with the private key for the fromAccount.

Multiple ways you can do this but I would suggest the way by setting `JsSignatureProvider`.

Another simple way you can use is by using the config Javascript Object with the options for Eos
and setting it's key provider like so,

`config.keyProvider = privateKey`

`eos = Eos(config)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the actor is wrong

have a look at this example

`let transferAction = (async () => {
  const result = await api.transact(
    {
      actions: [
        {
          account: "eosio.token",
          name: "transfer",
          authorization: [
            {
              actor: "useraaaaaaaa",
              permission: "active"
            }
          ],
          data: {
            from: "useraaaaaaaa",
            to: "useraaaaaaab",
            quantity: "0.0001 SYS",
            memo: ""
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      blocksBehind: 3,
      expireSeconds: 30
    }
  );
  console.dir(result);
})();`

this is a transfer from "useraaaaaaaa" to "useraaaaaaab"

you are transfering from  "accountFrom" to "accountTo" people who do not exist with no specification on amount and other things

Comment: I think that I am doing the same as explained, userFrom is alice, and userTo is bob same as useraaaaaaaa and useraaaaaaab. Am I missing something in your answer :) ?

Comment: I think he left the `signatures: [signatureProvider],` out.

Comment: @TeeAttack42 you pointed in the right direction, thank you. The problem was that I was providing the owner key of alice, and because I have owner and active private keys I had to use the active key and it worked. Additionally, I had to add 25.0000 because I was getting precision error.