# WAX - Signature error : "Message: transaction declares authority, but does not have signatures for it."

Tags: smart-contract, eosjs, eosio-code, blockchains

I'm trying to send a transaction from my react frontend to local chain, I have signed in wax cloud wallet and made a transaction. But at last I met this signature error.

```
"Message: transaction declares authority '{"actor":"mywarm.wam","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it."
```

I found that it is because the private key supplied to the signature provider is incorrect for the actor in which the transaction is being signed for. but I can't find the way to fix this
**Frontend Code**

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import * as waxjs from "@waxio/waxjs/dist";
// import SignatureProvider from 'eosjs-ledger-signature-provider';

function App() {

  const [wax, setWax] = useState('');
  const [signedAccount, setSignedAccount] = useState('');
  const [response, setResponse] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  // const signatureProvider = new SignatureProvider()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const wax = new waxjs.WaxJS({
      rpcEndpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888'
    });
    setWax(wax);
  }, [])

  const login = async () => {
    try {
      const userAccount = await wax.login();
      setSignedAccount(userAccount);
    } catch(e) {
      setResponse(e.message);
    }
  }

  const create = async () => {
    if(!wax.api) {
      setResponse('* Login first *');
    }

    try {
      const result = await wax.api.transact({
        actions: [{
          account: 'armyassets',
          name: 'createcol',
          authorization: [{
            actor: wax.userAccount,
            permission: 'active',
          }],
          data: {
            author: wax.userAccount,
            collection_name: "bbcollection",
            allow_notify: true,
            authorized_accounts: wax.userAccount,
            notify_accounts: wax.userAccount,
            market_fee: 0.1,
            data: [{
              key:"name",
              value:["string","bbcollection"],
            }],
          },
        }]
      }, {
        // signatures: [signatureProvider],
        blocksBehind: 3,
        expireSeconds: 1200
      });
      setMessage(JSON.stringify(result));
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      // await getCurrentMessage();
    } catch(e) {
      setMessage(e.message);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
          This is the test app for wax blockchain
      </header>
      <div className="App-content">
        <div className="App-button">
          <button onClick={login} className="login-btn">Login</button>
          <button onClick={create} className="sign-button">Create NFT</button>
        </div>
        <div className="App-account">
          <div>Signed User : </div>
          <div className="App-account-content">{signedAccount}</div>
        </div>    
      </div>
      <div className="App-response">
        Response: {response}
      </div>
      <div className="App-response">
        Message: {message}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have referenced this articles, but I still didn't find the solution.
[transaction declares authority '{"actor":"mymultisig11","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/transaction-declares-authority-actormymultisig11-permissionactive)
[Transaction requires authority, but does not have signatures for it](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/4482/transaction-requires-authority-but-does-not-have-signatures-for-it)
I have used development private key for eos on eos studio and deployed my smart contract code to local test net. And I signed in with my wax wallet account on my frontend, so the error might occur, I guess.
I also tried to make a transaction by using default actor on eos studio, but the same error appears.

```
 authorization: [{
            actor: "armyassets", //this is default actor on eos studio
            // actor: wax.userAccount,
            permission: 'active',
          }]
```

Please recommend any possible ways to deal with this.
Best Regards

Comment: I really think these guys just sabotages stuff so it goes bad every time I put a decent amount of money on one of my wax wallets it goes missing and every time I want to enjoy myself I can't make a signature and they refuse to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wax cloud wallet supports WAX chain. It'll not work with any other blockchain.

Comment: Hi, @MatthewDarwin, thanks. Yes, you are right. I heard of that just before. Someone recommend to use scatter for local test.. did you have experience in using it? I have read some articles to use scatter, but I didn't find clear one.. even when I tested it, it doesn't work well, Can you help me with scatter?